# Gaussian Pyramid Kernel & Gaussian blur

Tags: math, image-processing, computer-vision, gaussian, mat

If I have a function that does 5x5 Gaussian Pyramid Kernel, how do I use this function to produce Gaussian Blur on to an image?

I assume I have loop the whole image, but I am not sure how many times I have to call to function per row and per cols.

Comment: Are u using MatLab, Opencv? or others?

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply going to perform a blur, consider decomposing your 2D kernel into two 1D kernels for the sake of speed.

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/gsmooth.htm

The "Pyramid" context may be a bit misleading here; if you only want to blur an image and perhaps display the blurred image, or process it further, then image pyramids aren't necessarily relevant.